# Customize browser homepage when connected to my WIFI router

Tags: router, wifi

I am a owner of a small coffee shop. We have plenty of information online(facebook, twitter, getsatisfication etc...)

I am wondering that if I can customize my Wifi Router, so that we can offer links and a branding webpage to customers connected as homepage.(Homepage only, customers get full internet access).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this in numerous ways.  One simple way is to use the [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.org) replacement router firmware and the [Chillispot hotspot](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Chillispot).  For example, I use a Buffalo WHR-HP-G300N wireless router, which comes with dd-wrt preinstalled.